# is not a valid MVC template NEXTGEN

Tags: php, wordpress, nextgen-gallery, next-generation-plugin

I have a huge problem on migrating a wordpress site. After the migration I can't get to work the NEXTGEN GALLERY plugin.

When I try to upload an image or view options in admin, this is the message:

```
WAGNER/WWWROOT$/1a5ee4578.hostnd/htdocs/www/it/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/nextgen_basic_album/templates/nextgen_basic_album_gallery_display_ type.php
Is not a valid MVC template
```

I tried every solution available in all forums, but nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

if you haven't you can try those links
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/errors-referencing-mvc-template
http://www.nextgen-gallery.com/how-to-rollback-a-version/